# Template argument deduction/substitution failed:

Tags: c++

I have a compile error when using "output_array()" in a templated member function, the following code is a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int menu()
{
    int opt;
    cout << "\n**********MENU**********";
    cout << "\n1. Print the Array in reverse order";
    cin >> opt;
    return opt;
}

void input_array(int b[], int n)
{
    cout << "\nEnter the elements of the array";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> b[i];
    }
    return;
}

void output_array(int c[], int n)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        cout << c[j] << " ";
    }
    return;
}



void rev_arr(int b[], int n)
{
    int start = 0, end = n - 1;

    cout << "Array before reversing : " << output_array(b, n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
    {
        float temp = b[start];
        b[start] = b[end];
        b[end] = temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }

    cout << "Array after reversing : " << output_array(b, n);
    return;
}

void task(int b[], int n, int opt)
{
    switch (opt)
    {
    case 1:
        rev_arr(b, n);
        break;
    default:
        cout << "!!! Sorry Wrong Choice !!!";
    }
    return;
}

int main()
{
    int size;
    int a[50];
        cout << "\n You can Enter 50 elements in the array.\nHow much you want to enter?";
        cin >> size;

        input_array(a, size);
        int opt = menu();
        task(a, size, opt);
        

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Template argument deduction" is not a valid C concept — do not tag C++ questions with C too unless you are particularly fond of downvotes.

Comment: It is not clear where your 'template argument deduction' is coming into play — there are no explicit templates shown.  You should probably show the exact error message from exactly the code you show.  You might need to identify which o/s, compiler and options you are using, too.

Comment: Since `output_array()` doesn't return anything I'm not sure what you expect `cout << "Array before reversing : " << output_array(b, n);` to do.

Comment: After removing the lines that attempt to `cout` the results of a `void` function, this code compiles fine. Where is your error?

Comment: [OT]: `return;` as final statement in void function is unneeded.

Comment: why using `float` to swap 2 `int` ?

Answer (score 0):

The `output_array(int*, int)` is a printing function, not an `opertot<<` overlaod. Therefore, your can't place `output_arrry(b, n)` after `operator<<`. Simple separate into two statments:

Change

```
cout << "Array after reversing : " << output_array(b, n); // Not good.
```

into

```
cout << "Array after reversing : ";  output_array(b, n); // ok.
```

Or you have to write an `operator<<` overloading, give rules for `operator<<` to print you array. But, before doing this, you have to bind the size `n` in your array (as some kind of structure). The size is needed to be used in the function `operator<<`.